# Finding the average value of $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\cos(2 \pi f_0 (1+y_k)t)}$ where $y_k$ is a small random number

Tags: statistics, summation

The problem is

> Find an average value of $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\cos(2 \pi f_0 (1+y_k)t)},$$ where $y_k$ is picked randomly from the interval $\left[-\frac{\Delta f}{2f_0},\frac{\Delta f}{2f_0}\right]$.

$f_0$ is the center frequency and the distribution from which various $y_k$ are picked can be a Gaussian or uniform distribution, whichever is more simple for the purpose of the explanation. The width of the distribution is $\Delta f$. $t$ is just some parameter (like time which can take any value from $0$ to $\infty$)

Note that we want the average of an average of random cosines.

My first thought was to expand using $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ identity. However, $\sin(b)$ term cannot be neglected as $2\pi f_0 t$ factor can be as large as possible.

I have literally no idea how to go about solving it because $y_k$ is a random variable.

Comment: Hi. Seeing that you are not new to the MSE community, I hope you understand that your question  is phrased as an isolated question. Without further context or showing us your attempts to solve the problem, you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the Taylor expansion for $\cos(x)$ and writing the sum as a sum of moments of $y_k$?

Comment: @Joseph Camacho I'm not sure I understand. How do the moments of $y_k$ come in?

Comment: Oh, I probably misread your problem.  When you said "average value" I read that as "expected value", in which case the moments would come in as the expected value of powers of $y_k$.

Comment: To echo @JosephCamacho "average value" would be interpreted by most Readers to mean the expected value of the sum, given a uniform distribution of $y_k$ on the interval.  However you've used most of your notation with defining or otherwise introducing it.  What is $\Delta f$? Is it the difference between $f_0$ and $f_1$? (What are they?)  What is $t$?  Your Question likely has a simple answer if you can simply define the notation.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. I added more clarifications to the problem.

Comment: An important principle here is the [linearity of expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), so that the average of those cosine averages is going to be the same as the cosine's average if they are all the same distribution (Gaussian or uniform on the same interval).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. Would the answer then just be $\left<\cos(2 \pi f_0 t (1+y))\right>=\int{p(y) \cos (2 \pi f_0 t (1+y))} dy$ where $p(y)$ is whichever probability distribution of the $y_k$ ?

Comment: Use Euler formula for the cosine. The expectation value of each terms then evaluates to a characteristic function.

Comment: Right, you would just integrate the expression with respect to what probability density function on $[-\Delta f/2f_0,+\Delta f/2f_0]$ is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is customary to designate random variables with uppercase letters, so we will replace the $y_k$ notation in the Question with $Y_k$, reserving lowercase for ordinary (real) values below.

Any problem asking for the "average value" of an expression involving a random variable must specify the probability distribution of the values it takes.  Here assume all the $Y_k$ random variables have a continuous probability density $p(y)$ on the common interval $[-\Delta f/2f_0,+\Delta f/2f_0]$.

The the "average value" of the summation is also known as the *expected value*:

$$ \mathbb E\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\cos(2 \pi f_0 (1+Y_k)t)}\right) $$

Given the probability density function $p(y)$ one compute the expected value by integrating:

$$ \int_{-\Delta f/2f_0}^{+\Delta f/2f_0} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}{\cos(2 \pi f_0 (1+y)t)} p(y) dy $$

Since the sum has finitely many terms, the order of integration and summation can be swapped (linearity of expectation).  But in this case the interval of integration, the probability distribution, and the integrand are all the same, so dividing the sum by $N$ just gives a single term to integrate:

$$ \int_{-\Delta f/2f_0}^{+\Delta f/2f_0} \cos(2 \pi f_0 (1+y)t) p(y) dy $$

To evaluate the integral requires one to supply the desired density function $p(y)$.  The simplest case is a uniform distribution on $[-\Delta f/2f_0,+\Delta f/2f_0]$, so that $p(y)$ is a constant function:

$$ p(y) = \frac{f_0}{\Delta f} $$

Now a $u$-substitution $u = 2\pi f_0 (1+y)t$ makes the integration a routine exercise.